# Android tablet not recognizing external keyboard?

Tags: tablet, external-keyboard

I have a Tablet running Android 4.0.3. Its DOMO x3g, works fine except that when I connect an external usb keyboard to it,it doesn't show up any recognition or anything.While USB pen drives, hard drives easily work on the tab... Any solutions?

Comment: Is it a standard 'HID' keyboard-device, or a more complex USB keyboard? *Check this on a PC (Windows or Linux).*

Comment: Hello, sorry to burry out this thread, but I had the same issue and I found out my issue on my Android TV (V8) that did not reconize my keyboard. That was due to the Android developper enabled. Go to `Settings` > `Developer options` menu and uncheck `USB debugging`. Voila !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I had the same issue, it never worked for any PC USB Keyboards, except the one which we bought from DOMO, that nCase K6. That K6 worked perfectly (even to my PC). But a PC USB mouse worked on my DOMO Slate X3G. Buy a nCase K6 or, preferably you could install USB Host Controller from Play Store, as said by the first answer.. That should fix your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Install [USB Host Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.sztupy.android.usbhostcontroller) from Google Play, and run it.

Comment: If possible, please provide a link to the app. :)

Comment: Any explanations to the background, why this app should help -- or at least what it does?